# MPI: What to do when number of expected MPI_Recv is unkown

Tags: c, mpi

I've got many slave nodes which might or might not send messages to the master node. So currently there's no way the master node knows how many MPI_Recv to expect. Slave nodes had to sent minimum number of messages to the master node for efficiency reasons.

I managed to find [a cool trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431180/what-should-i-do-for-recieving-when-the-number-of-send-messages-is-unknown-in-mp), which sends an additional "done" message when its no longer expecting any messages. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in my case, where there're variable number of senders. Any idea on how to go about this? Thanks!

```
if(rank == 0){ //MASTER NODE

    while (1) {

        MPI_Recv(&buffer, 10, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        if (status.MPI_TAG == DONE) break;


        /* Do stuff */
    }

}else{ //MANY SLAVE NODES

    if(some conditions){
        MPI_Send(&buffer, 64, MPI_INT, root, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

}


MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(NULL, 1, MPI_INT, root, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Not working, the program seem to be still waiting for a MPI_Recv

Comment: Just tried it, I think MPI_Barrier is being executed but the `is after barrier` message is never printed, as the program get stuck at the MPI_Recv

Comment: Rank 0 never calls the Barrier so obviously it hangs. Remove the Barrier and it will run.

Comment: It actually ran without halting but then it executes `MPI_Send(NULL, 1, MPI_INT, root, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` right after the first slave node is done computing..without waiting for other slave nodes

Comment: tried moving the `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` inside `else` clause still hangs at MPI_Recv

Comment: You can't call Barrier on a subset of the comm. Make a subcomm composed of worker processes or sync them another way.

Comment: Also, every proc sends DONE to the root, including the root. The other procs calls to Send will never be matched. You should draw up a scheme of your algorithm and think about the details, rather than just tweaking the code.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler and more elegant option would be to use the `MPI_IBARRIER`. Have each worker call all of the sends that it needs to and then call `MPI_IBARRIER` when it's done. On the master, you can loop on both an `MPI_IRECV` on `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and an `MPI_IBARRIER`. When the `MPI_IBARRIER` is done, you know that everyone has finished and you can cancel the `MPI_IRECV` and move on. The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
if (master) {
  /* Start the barrier. Each process will join when it's done. */
  MPI_Ibarrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);

  do {
    /* Do the work */
    MPI_Irecv(..., MPI_ANY_SOURCE, &requests[1]);

    /* If the index that finished is 1, we received a message.
     * Otherwise, we finished the barrier and we're done. */
    MPI_Waitany(2, requests, &index, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
  } while (index == 1);

  /* If we're done, we should cancel the receive request and move on. */
  MPI_Cancel(&requests[1]);
} else {
  /* Keep sending work back to the master until we're done. */
  while( ...work is to be done... ) {
    MPI_Send(...);
  }

  /* When we finish, join the Ibarrier. Note that
   * you can't use an MPI_Barrier here because it
   * has to match with the MPI_Ibarrier above. */
  MPI_Ibarrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
  MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- you called `MPI_Barrier` in wrong place, it should be called after `MPI_Send`.
2- the root will exit from loop when it receives `DONE` from all other ranks (size -1).

the code after some modifications:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Status status;
    int DONE = 888;
    int buffer = 77;
    int root = 0 ;
    printf("here is rank %d with size=%d\n" , rank , size);fflush(stdout);
    int num_of_DONE = 0 ;
 if(rank == 0){ //MASTER NODE


    while (1) {

        MPI_Recv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("root recev %d from %d with tag = %d\n" , buffer , status.MPI_SOURCE , status.MPI_TAG );fflush(stdout);

        if (status.MPI_TAG == DONE)
        num_of_DONE++;
    printf("num_of_DONE=%d\n" , num_of_DONE);fflush(stdout);
    if(num_of_DONE == size -1)
        break;



        /* Do stuff */
    }

}else{ //MANY SLAVE NODES

    if(1){
        buffer = 66;
        MPI_Send(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, root, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("rank %d sent data.\n" , rank);fflush(stdout);
    }

}

    if(rank != 0)
    {
        buffer = 55;
        MPI_Send(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, root, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }


    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("rank %d done.\n" , rank);fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
    hosam@hosamPPc:~/Desktop$ mpicc -o aa aa.c
    hosam@hosamPPc:~/Desktop$ mpirun -n 3 ./aa
here is rank 2 with size=3
here is rank 0 with size=3
rank 2 sent data.
here is rank 1 with size=3
rank 1 sent data.
root recev 66 from 1 with tag = 1
num_of_DONE=0
root recev 66 from 2 with tag = 1
num_of_DONE=0
root recev 55 from 2 with tag = 888
num_of_DONE=1
root recev 55 from 1 with tag = 888
num_of_DONE=2
rank 0 done.
rank 1 done.
rank 2 done.
```

Comment: I just tried your approach, unfortunately it terminated earlier than it should have. Each slave nodes takes their own time to do their computations, last node in grid doesn't mean that it supposed to terminate last. I think `sleep(1)` would do the trick if the last process takes less then 1 second to compute..

Comment: @kornesh : I modified the answer.

Comment: Thats an elegant way but _Slave nodes had to sent minimum number of messages to the master node for efficiency reasons_